# Is there a word similar to 'multiple' that means 'n-ary' (as in 'unary, binary, ..')?

Tags: word-request

I want to use one word to say a function takes multiple inputs. Is there a counterpart of 'multiple' in the 'unary, binary, ternary...' family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Multiary*.  You can also say *polyadic*, though it doesn't meet your requirement of having *-ary*.

Still, you should probably make it clear what you mean by these words if you use them, since they're relatively uncommon.  For example, you could say "*n*-ary for some *n* ≥ 2".

Comment: *Really*? Wow, +1 just for teaching me a new word. (And also because it's the right answer, but you know. Details.) I really didn't think any such word would exist, nice find. Did you already know both of those, or did you research them? :) Time to edit out the part of my answer that says there is no "-ary" word. Nice job!

Comment: Ah, be careful with [*polyadic*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/polyadic) though! The definitions I found say it refers to 3 or more items, so if the function in question had only two arguments the word wouldn't be applicable.

Comment: Huh! Okay, this has turned into way too many comments on your answer, but I just found something else out as well. According to [this Wikipedia page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Arity#Multiary) at least, in a *programming-specific context*, the word the OP is searching for is *n-ary*, and *multiary* has an entirely different meaning: it means that the function can take a variable number of arguments (ie. sometimes it might take two, other times one, etc.). There are several other "ary" definitions in that link as well.

Comment: Hmm!  Well, I think you can define these words multiple ways because they're relatively uncommon, which is why I said at the end you should say what you mean by them if you use them.  I think a polyadic *function* is generally a function that takes *two* or more arguments, not three.  I'm less confident about *multiary*; I hadn't seen the definition you gave here before.  You can see [elsewhere on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Other_names) an assertion that agrees with mine, at any rate.

Comment: Another citation for *polyadic function* meaning *n* ≥ 2: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178827/what-does-polyadic-mean-in-the-context-of-functional-programming-and-type-syst

Comment: Even more interesting! I wish Wikipedia wouldn't contradict itself, but I suppose that's the nature of the beast ;) Well, all right then. You just had me intrigued and I went on a research-trip and thought I'd share my findings :)

Comment: Side note: As snailboat says, this is a rare and obscure word. My general opinion is that if you're going to use a word that you know will be unfamiliar to most of your readers, you should tell them what it means on first use. If you're only going to use it once, it's usually better to use a more-familiar word, or a phrase if necessary. I believe that the purpose of writing should be to convey information to the reader, and not to impress him with how smart the writer must be. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an "ary" word with this meaning (since the initial writing of this post, [snailboat's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8269/289) has proven me wrong; however as the "ary" word is quite uncommon I still feel the rest of this answer could be useful).

I think your best bet in this scenario is to hyphenate if you really must have a single word; you might try calling it a "multi-parameter" function (or "multi-argument"). You could even spell out the whole word "multiple", and you could use the suggested "input" from your question: "multiple-input function" would also make perfect sense. All of these are perfectly understandable, and to the best of my knowledge they're the closest you can come to a single-word solution.